# PostGIS how to use ST_Retile

Tags: postgis, raster, tiles

How do you properly use ST_Retile https://postgis.net/docs/RT_Retile.html

there are no directions for it

tried:

```
update slopes.dem_slope set rast=st_retile(rast,100,100)
```

and

```
select st_retile('slopes.dem_slope','rast',100,100)
```

and

```
select st_retile('slopes.dem_slope'::regclass,'rast',100,100)
```

all throwing errors

Comment: The linked page shows that this function wants at least seven parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must provide all [required parameters](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_Retile.html). Parameter values must have proper type, e.g. setting tile size `tw=100` is correct, but `tw=100.0` will not work.

```sql
CREATE TABLE 
    rasters.global_dem_retiled
AS 
SELECT 
    st_retile(
        'rasters.global_dem', -- source raster table
        'rast',               -- raster column
        ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(ST_Envelope(rast)), 4326),  
        0.05::float8,         -- pixel size
        0.05::float8, 
        100::int,             -- tile size
        100::int,
        'bilinear' -- Any supported by GDAL algorithm, eg. average, min, max, ...
    ) AS rast 
FROM
    rasters.global_dem
;
```